# "../" (back directory) not working on PHP in Windows

Tags: php, windows, debugging

I have no clue why it's not working but when I go to debug my code it doesn't work and just throws an error like this:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../classes/John/settings.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

Directory Structure:
http://gyazo.com/220cf2d603f8f1267260b2dd72d2d46d

Comment: We can't help you if you don't include the directory structure.

Comment: What's the current working directory? http://au1.php.net/getcwd

Comment: Just added the structure

Comment: Where did you get the error? I'm assuming it's a file in Meekro directory. You should use DOCUMENT_ROOT as leshy said. Try: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/John/settings.php'

Comment: in config.php while including settings.php

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be performing includes relative to the current directory. What if you wanted to move that file? All of the links would break. A way to ensure that you can still link to other files, while retaining those links if you move your file, is: 
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'directory/directory/file');

DOCUMENT_ROOT is a server variable that represents the base directory that your code is located within.